# performance - replace using regular expresson in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea and a function is called on keyup event of this textarea.

The function processes the text entered in the textarea using regular expressions. This function will be repeatedly invoked as it is tied to keydown event.

Therefore i would like to write the regular expressions in such a way I get maximum performance.

Consider the following code as an example and the functions defined will be invoked repeatedly on key down event.

```js
    var map = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'};

    function covert(m)
    {
        return map[m];
    }

    var msg = 'aaaaaaaaaa2aaaaa2';
    var r1 = new RegExp('\\d', 'g');
    var r1L = /\d/g;
    var test;


    function t1()
    {
        test = msg.replace(r1, function (m)
        {
            return map[m];
        });
        return test;
    }
    console.log(t1());

    function t2()
    {
        test = msg.replace(r1L, function (m)
        {
            return map[m];
        });
        return test;
    }
    console.log(t2());

    function t3()
    {
        test = msg.replace(r1L, covert);
        return test;
    }
    console.log(t3());

    function t4()
    {
        test = msg.replace(r1, covert);
        return test;
    }
   console.log(t4());


    function t5()
    {
        test = msg.replace(/\d/g, function (m)
        {
            return map[m];
        });
        return test;
    }
    console.log(t5());


    function t6()
    {
        test = msg.replace(/\d/g, covert);
        return test;
    }
    console.log(t6());
```

After going through regular expression details, i thought function t3() will give maximum performance because it uses the global variable r1L (literal regexp) and named function.

I have tested it using https://jsperf.com/basic-js/

However, in firefox, t2() is giving maximum performance and in chrome and IE t6() is giving maximum performance.

I am new to coding and first time writing something for performance. There may be errors in my test cases also. Please let me know which approach I should select. Please explain why a particular approach gives faster result in a particular browser.

Comment: jspref can run these functions over two million times per second. How many `keydown` events are you expecting!?

Comment: @Kobi, i used setTimeout to cancel previous tasks and to restrict the repeated calls such that only one call per second is made. so u suggest not to bother much about performance in my case?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Did you encounter any performance issues when using any of these?

Comment: @Sweeper, no. i did not face any performance issue.

Comment: @Kiran Then don't worry about it. From the tests, the slowest is just 7% slower. I would say it's not that significant.

Comment: thanks Sweeper. i now understand i was unnecessarily giving focus on performance. But just curious to know why different browsers give different speeds for these?